# how to pass DataTable var from jsf (primefaces) to managedBean?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I have a first dataTable with a list of jobs, for each job of the list I wan't to create a second dataTable (inside the first ) with triggersList this is my jsf page :

```
<p:dataTable id="jobs" var="job" value="#{jobBean.jobList}" rowKey="job.key">
    <f:facet name="header">  
            Jobs List 
    </f:facet>
<p:column headerText="Name">  
        #{job.key.name}   
    </p:column>
<p:column headerText="Group">  
        #{job.key.group}  
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Triggers">
    <p:dataTable id="triggers" var="trigger" value="#{jobBean.triggerList}">
    <p:column headerText="Start Time">  
                #{trigger.startTime}   
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
 </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

So for each job var I wan't to have triggers List, this is my managedBean :

```
public class JobBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{job}")
private JobDetail job;
    private List<Trigger> triggerList;

   ....


        /**
 * @param triggerList
 *            the triggerList to set
 */
public void setTriggerList(List<Trigger> triggerList) {
    this.triggerList = triggerList;
}

/**
 * @return the triggerList
 */
public List<Trigger> getTriggerList() {
    this.get();
    return triggerList;
}

private void get(){
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    JobDetail jb = ctx.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(ctx, "# {job}", JobDetail.class);
    this.triggerList = triggerListMap.get(jb.getKey());
}



    /**
 * @param job
 *            the job to set
 */
public void setJob(JobDetail job) {
    this.job = job;
}

/**
 * @return the job
 */
public JobDetail getJob() {
    return job;
}
```

}

The get() method return a null pointer Exception :

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tti.frameworkBI.web.JobBean.get(JobBean.java:129)**

Comment: You've got a `triggerListMap` variable which suddenly appears in your bean without being previously declared. That's not obviously your real bean. Please try to post tested code pieces, with relevant code and easing people to copy-paste and try them. See the [SSCCE document](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with findComponent and getRowData() :

```
public List<Trigger> getTriggerList() {
        this.get();
        return triggerList;
    }

private void get() {
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getViewRoot().findComponent("form:jobs");
    JobDetail jb = (JobDetail) dataTable.getRowData();
    this.triggerList = this.jobServiceImpl.getAllTriggers(scheduler,
            jb.getKey());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is declare the triggerlist inside the JobDetails class and use it like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="jobs" var="job" value="#{jobBean.jobList}" rowKey="job.key">
      <f:facet name="header">  
                Jobs List 
        </f:facet>
<p:column headerText="Name">  
         #{job.key.name}   
     </p:column>
<p:column headerText="Group">  
         #{job.key.group}  
     </p:column>
<p:column headerText="Triggers">
     <p:dataTable id="triggers" var="trigger" value="#{job.triggerList}">
        <p:column headerText="Start Time">  
                    #{trigger.startTime}   
        </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
</p:column>
     </p:dataTable> code here
```

Comment: the problem that the JobDetail Class is provided by the Quartz Framework that I'm using.

Comment: Maybe you can extend JobDetail Class in  new one with the triggerlist.

Comment: I've just found a simple solution.